# Angular Material MatTableDataSource with Firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have a data table that is being populated with data coming from Firestore. I also used MatTableDataSource to implement pagination, sorting, and filtering.  All 3 work fine but for some reason my data only loads once when the page is refreshed.  If I go to another page and then back to the table the data is gone.  I'm at a loss as to why this is happening. Below is my code.

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Account } from './../models/account.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AccountService {
  accountsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Account>;
  accounts: Observable<Account[]>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.accountsCollection = afs.collection('accounts');

    this.accounts = this.accountsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Account;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    });

  }

  getAccounts() {
    return this.accounts;
  }

}
```

**Component**

```
import { Account } from './../../../models/account.model';
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { AccountService } from '../../../services/account.service';
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account-table',
  templateUrl: './account-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account-table.component.css']
})
export class AccountTableComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Account>();
  displayedColumns = [
    'salesStep',
    'status',
    'idn',
    'hospital',
    'state',
    'regionalManager',
    'accountExecutive',
    'clientLiaison',
    'gpo'
  ];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.accountService.getAccounts().subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
      console.log(this.dataSource.data);
    });
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="example-header">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput #filter (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<mat-card class="example-container">

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- Sales Step Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="salesStep">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Sales Step </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.salesStep}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Status Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Status </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.status}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- IDN Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="idn">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> IDN </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.idn}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Hospital Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="hospital">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Hospital </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.hospital}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- State Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="state">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> State </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.state}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Regional Manager Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="regionalManager">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> RM </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.regionalManager}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Account Executive Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="accountExecutive">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> AE </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.accountExecutive}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Client Liaison Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="clientLiaison">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> CL </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.clientLiaison}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- GPO Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="gpo">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> GPO </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.gpo}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>



    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
    </mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <!-- <div class="example-no-results"
       [style.display]="(accountService.accounts | async)?.length">
    No accounts found matching filter.
  </div> -->

  <mat-paginator #paginator
                [pageSize]="10"
                [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
  </mat-paginator>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch data once with Observables in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530108/fetch-data-once-with-observables-in-angular-2)

Comment: I think my problem is that I'm only fetching it once which explains why the data disappears after router change.  I think it has something to do with MatTableDataSource but I'm too much of a newb to know.

Comment: just check the above link..it explains the same

Comment: I️ read I‎t over and I️ think I️ need more context to understand I‎t fully.  I️ wish there was an example with angularfire2.  I️ appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may work better for the getAccounts method:

```
  getAccountsX() {
    return this.afs.collection<Account[]>('accounts').snapshotChanges().map((accounts) => {
      return accounts.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Account;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data }
      });
    });
  }
```

I have never tried making a firestore call in the constructor of the service but always make the database calls in a method that gets called during the ngOnInit in my component.

So in the component you could have a object `accounts: Observable<Account[]>` that is of type `Observable<Account[]>` and set it to equal getAccountsX(). Then in your markup I would *ngIf the entire table like this: `*ngIf="(accounts | async) as acts"`. Then the dataSource would actually be `acts`. I have never used the DataTable yet but this is just an approach I would take to try and keep the subscription to the data active. If you want I can EDIT your question with this.

EDIT:

Here is an explanation of two separate ways to handle that subscription:

So here in my Component I am fetching the Observable and then also subscribing to it to save the array of whatever data model you are fetching:

```
  accountsObservable: Observable<Account[]>;
  accountsArray: Account[];

  constructor(
    private ds: DatabaseService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.accountsObservable = this.ds.getAccountsX();

    this.accountsObservable.subscribe(accounts => {
      this.accountsArray = accounts;
    });
  }
```

Then here in my markup you can create the subscription using *ngFor and the ASYNC pipe, or simply loop through the array after it has been acknowledged by the subscription:

```
<!-- This div below is subscribing to the Observable in markup using the 'async' pipe to make sure it waits for data -->
<div id="markup-subscription" *ngFor="let act of (accountsObservable | async)">
  <p>{{ act?.id }}</p>
</div>

<!-- This div below is looping through the array that was pulled from the subscription of the Observable -->
<div id="component-subscription" *ngFor="let act of accountsArray">
  <p>{{ act?.id }}</p>
</div>
```

One reason for waiting for the subscription in the Component code is if there is a need to manipulate the data before spitting it out on the UI. I believe if you are using the second option of subscribing in the Component code instead of your markup you would want to make sure the *ngFor isn't trying to loop through an empty Array as the subscription may not have set the array before the content wants to load on the DOM. So I would `*ngIf` the accountsArray to make sure it is set first like so:

```
<div id="component-subscription" *ngIf="accountsArray" *ngFor="let act of accountsArray">
```

Granted this is not using the MatDataTable as I wanted to show an example of how these subscriptions work and the goal is to use one subscription

In regards to unsubscribing, the reason that is not an option is because you must set the Observable subscription to a variable like so:

```
    const subscription = this.accountsObservable.subscribe(accounts => {
      this.accountsArray = accounts;
    });

    subscription.unsubscribe();
```

I hope this can help explain the state of the subscription as you are looping through the collection or document in the UI.

Comment: This actually ended up working without *ngIf="(accounts | async) as acts".  In the console it grabs the data every time I router change to the table.  Do I still have to implement ngOnDestroy and unsubscribe?  When I subscribe to the new getAccountsX method in the component it returns an <Account[]> which is what I pass to MatTableDataSource.  It's not a subscription so I'm unable to unsubscribe from it.  I'm still slightly confused as to when I unsubscribe from a subscription.  I really appreciate your help, your answer was perfect and lead me in the right direction!

Comment: Hey Kyle, I made some edits above that will hopefully help explain how that subscription works.

Comment: Thank you Nick this really helps me!  So if I have something like this...
`const subscriptionOne = this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params.get('account');
      const subscriptionTwo = this.accountService.getAccount(id).subscribe((account: Account) => {
        this.dataSource.data = this.account;
      });
    });`

Would I have to say...
`ngOnDestroy() {
this.subscriptionOne.unsubscribe()
this.subscriptionTwo.unsubscribe()
}`

?

Comment: The reason I ask about using the unsubscribe method is because I'm not sure how to use the async pipe on the mat-table since it's iterating though dataSource which is an array coming from MatTableDataSource.  Wouldn't dataSource have to be an observable in order to use async?

Comment: So what the async pipe is doing there is subscribing to the observable and handing the array thats returned to the dataSource after its acknowledged the array data so instead of saying `[dataSource]="dataSource"` you would say `[dataSource]="(dataSource | async)"` and that is creating your subscription. In regards to the first comment, I believe those const variables should house the subscription and then yes calling unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy will work.

Comment: Actually for the getAccount(id) call you want to do this: `this.accountObservable = this.accountService.getAccount(id);` and then after that `const subscriptionTwo = this.accountObservable.subscribe((account) => { this.dataSource = account })`. Take note that `subscriptionOne` and `subscriptionTwo` must be globally available to your component and not `const` variables created in the `ngOnInit` to call them in your `ngOnDestroy` and unsubscribe.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas!  I also am using a mat-table and had the subscription in my service constructor (after following a different tutorial).  My table was constantly populated but my issue was if I added anything to the database and then routed back to the component with the mat-table rows would be duplicated.  It seemed that every time I added a record the mat-table DataSource was holding on to the old data as well as receiving the updated set.  Moving to your strategy cleaned it right up.

Answer (score 1):

try the simplest brother. here.

```
constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.accountsCollection = afs.collection('accounts');
}

getAccounts() {
    return this.accounts = this.accountsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Account;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    });
  }
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Save the subscription you get from getAccounts().subscribe and call unsubscribe() to it in ngOnDestroy. I didn't test but it might help if af2 caches the subscriptions, as the observable never completes on it's own. Necessary and good practice for avoiding memory leaks anyway.