# return result from observable in JS

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I have a function that has an observable object and I need to return the value of the fetch that I use in this function. But I don't know why I can not return the result when I display the result it is totally fine but when I try to return it is empty.

I check a few similar problems but they were very complex and also they didn't match my case and also after trying one or two of them still the problem exists.

```
function getRandomQuote() {
    const obs$ = Observable.create(async(observer) => {
        const result = await fetch(RANDOM_QUOTE_API_URL)
            .then(Response => Response.json())
            .then(data => data.content)

        observer.next(result)
        console.log(result)
    })

    return obs$.subscribe(x => { return x })
}
```

I tried to use return only inside the subscribe part but it doesn't work and in one of the similar cases they tried to return the outer part which I tried and still not work

I am new with observable and JavaScrip I just need to return this value and use it in another function.
thank you

Comment: why you are trying to return this? you can subscribe this from any component to get data.

Comment: I want to use it in this function

`async function renderNewQuote() {

    const quote = await getRandomQuote()
    quoteDisplayElement.innerHTML = ''
    quote.split('').forEach(character => {
        const characterSpan = document.createElement('span')
        characterSpan.innerText = character
        quoteDisplayElement.appendChild(characterSpan)
    })
    quoteInputElement.value = null
    startTimer()
}`
how I can subscribe it in here

Comment: can you please check the first answer from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530108/fetch-data-once-with-observables-in-angular-2 . First create Observer and subscribe to get data @AliDK

Comment: better return the observable, and subscribe to it from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `Observable` other than `Subscription`

```
function getRandomQuote() {
    return Observable.create(async(observer) => {
        const result = await fetch(RANDOM_QUOTE_API_URL)
            .then(Response => Response.json())
            .then(data => data.content)
        observer.next(result)
    })
}
//usage 
    getRandomQuote().subscribe(console.log)
```

Or there is `defer()` and `from()` operator which helps you convert promise to observable

```
getRandomQuote=()=>defer(()=>from(fetch(RANDOM_QUOTE_API_URL)
            .then(Response => Response.json())
            .then(data => data.content))

//usage 
getRandomQuote().subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: Thank you for help first I didn't figure it out but finally, I understand that instead of returning value I can write my function inside the subscribe